# How do I take a movie with my integrated webcam in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, video, webcam

How do I take a video in windows 7? I've downloaded both windows movie maker 2.6 and windows movie maker live, but neither can actually take a video with the integrated webcam on my laptop. I know the webcam works as face recognition with the program Fast-Access always logs me in. (this was so easy in windows vista, but after the upgrade to 7 I just can't seem to figure out how to do it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've noticed that the web cam software was available from the computer manufacturer and not so much in generic windows software (like [dell webcam central](http://dell-webcam-central.software.informer.com/) was what I was looking for). The manufacturer is usually the one that distributes the driver software for their webcam, I was looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in their infinite wisdom, the nice folks at Microsoft have removed certain features (such as webcam capturing) from the current version of Windows Live Movie Maker.

But all is not lost: one developer decided to take matters into his own hands and create a portable version of Windows Movie Maker based on Movie Maker 2.1 (with all the bells 'n' whistles). You can run **[Portable Windows Movie Maker](http://devrexster.googlepages.com/mmk)** on any computer with Windows XP, Vista, or 7. And since it's portable, you can run it from a USB flash drive or a folder on your hard drive without installing it.